# Share file between two Android devices using Rx Java socket programming

Tags: android, sockets, rx-java

I have successfully paired two Android devices using Wifi direct.After that i am able to send and receive files over socket. I want to use RxJava for sending and  Receiving files over socket.
I have searched a lot but unable to find any example or tutorial on the same. 
Can somebody provides me any links to proceed on the same?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a utility that aims to do exactly that:
https://github.com/mayfourth/WiFi-Direct-File-Transfer. It looks like it contains everything that you should need. Just browse the code and see how it should be done.

P.S. The question, the way you wrote it, is pretty generic. And it also asks for a solution without showing what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. It's like you think you are going to get the code you need on a silver platter. I would speculate that this lead to your downvote and I would ask you to consider taking at this post: https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Actually i am able to pair devices using wifi direct and even able to send files across. I am just looking for how to use rxJava or reactive programing for observing data on socket.?

Comment: This is a library that might help: https://github.com/jacek-marchwicki/JavaWebsocketClient. You can either use it as it is, or browse the code to see it's internal mechanics for inspiration.